# Where to place the script that is accessible in multiple pages in rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, dry

I have three functions say add(), subtract() and multiply() and I have two pages using the same function in script and I want it to put it somewhere common so that it is not repeated. I tried to put it as

```
<script>
function add(number) {}
function subtract(number) {}
function multiply(number) {}
</script>
```

in application.html.erb but it is available in all pages. So I want it to be accessible only for those two pages. Where should I use this and how?

Answer (score 1):

create a seperate js file with Add(), subtract() and multiply() function and link this js file to two pages.

Comment: <%= javascript_include_tag update_details %> shows up error like Asset filtered out and will not be served: add`Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( update_details.js )` to `config/initializers/assets.rb`

Comment: @Logesh, the error explains what you have to do to make it work

Answer (score 1):

You are not making use of rails asset pipeline by writing your script in views. If you look at [`rail guides`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) it says

`Asset pipeline concatenate assets, which can reduce the number of requests that a browser makes to render a web page. Web browsers are limited in the number of requests that they can make in parallel, so fewer requests can mean faster loading for your application.`

So you should use it.

What you can do it make a separate file lets say update_details.js in app/assets/javascript directory then require that file in application.js by

```
//= require update_details
```

or if you have //= require_tree . in application.js then it'll automatically load up all the js files inside app/assets/javascript folder so you don't need to require that update_details separately. After that you can simply link application.js in your layout by using

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

**OR**

If you want to load up only update_details and leave all other js files then you can use

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "update_details" %>
```

in your layout and also don't forget to include it in your assets precompile path by

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( jquery.inview.min.js  update_details.js )
```

Comment: Thank you. I understand and I have already added Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( jquery.inview.min.js ) and can I simply append the update_details.js to it?

Comment: Thank you. I will make use of it and I will mark as answer after using it.

Answer (score 0):

**Unobtrusive**

You seem to be missing the point of the [`asset pipeline`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#how-to-use-the-asset-pipeline) - 
put those functions into a Javascript file, which you'll call from the pages you want it to run on.

Rails does this with the `layout` of your application:

```
#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

--

**application.js**

Currentely, you're *including* Javascript directly in a view, or your layout. This is not only [WET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself#DRY_vs_WET_solutions), but also will prevent you from being able to use the JS you need in the future.

To fix this, you will be best putting your functions into its own file. You can either *create* a file, or put into the `application.js` file - which is present in ALL Rails applications:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
function add(number) {}
function subtract(number) {}
function multiply(number) {}
```

Because `application.js` is called from your *layout*, any page which uses that layout will then have that Javascript functionality ready to go

--

You should definitely [read up on the asset pipeline for Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#how-to-use-the-asset-pipeline)